# How can I style a TabView?

Tags: version-7, gui-construction, display

I have been trying to style a `TabView` like in the examples on the Wolfram CDF site, where they have custom sizes and backgrounds with images or gradients, but I am struggling to find documentation on how to style `TabViews`

Is there a way in *Mathematica* I can list all the properties of a control like `TabView` or just those controls which can be modified by the user?

Edit: [Link to an example of styling done by Wolfram](http://www.wolfram.co.uk/cdf/uses-examples/investment-statements.html)

Comment: Please add some links so everyone else can see what exactly are You describing. Meanwhile You can check `??TabView`.

Comment: Thanks Kuba the ?? is something i had not discovered before. I have added a link to CDF example on the Wolfram site that has used the `TabView` and styled it to be very different from the default look.

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded and examined the CDF you refer to. I conclude from my examination that what looks like a highly stylized `TabView` may actually be a custom control built based on `EvenHandler`. Often when one sees what look like fancy versions of *Mathematica* controls in sophisticated CDFs, they are custom replacements such as the one you were looking at.

As far as I know there is not much customization available for `TabView` (more experienced *Mathematica* users may be able to successfully dispute this). However, you could get a fair amount of look-and-feel control by replacing a `TabView` by a `Row` of buttons because buttons are easily styled.

Here is an example.

The standard, un-stylized look

```
Row[{Button["Foo", Print["foo"]], Button["Bar", Print["bar"]]}]
```

[image: standard]

A stylized version

```
Row[{
  Button[Style["Foo", 24, White, Background -> Red], Print["foo"], Appearance -> None],
  Button[Style["Bar", 24, White, Background -> Blue], Print["bar"], Appearance -> None]
}, " "]
```

[image: fancy]

Answer (score 0):

This is actually not related to `TabView` per se, although it might look that way if you're not used to GUI construction in *Mathematica*. `TabView` is just one of many GUI elements. Like some other elements such as `SlideView`, `TabView` encapsulates graphics. But it doesn't style the graphics that it encapsulates it. The content of `TabView` or `SlideView` looks that way independently of what encapsulates it. For example:

```
TabView[{
  Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, Background -> White, ImagePadding -> 50],
  Plot[Cos[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, Background -> White, ImagePadding -> 50]
  }]
```

[image: example 1]

If you take the first `Plot` command and execute it outside `TabView` it will look the same.

So the question is not how can we style `TabView` to get something like what we see in the example you gave us. The answer is that we have to build such an interface outside of `TabView` and then put it in.

I will leave it for you to experiment more with GUI construction, for which there are tutorials in the documentation and online as well. But the main building block is `Grid` or `Row` and `Column` respectively. That's how you can divide up the screen estate into block that you can fill with content such as menus and charts.